# Google Chrome Extension - Get Tab Contents in a String

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am creating a Google Chrome extension and I need to import the page HTML into my extension as a string so that it can be used.

I have tried:

```
document.getElementById('container');
```

But I get a "null" in return. I have made sure that it is the correct div id.

Is there something wrong with the code I am using or does this method simply not work?

Comment: Did you try `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]`?

Comment: When I try that it gives: [object HTMLBodyElement]

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML` will give you the html of the whole `body` tag.

Answer (score 1):

To get your container div as String you shoud use **innerText** or **innerHTML**.

As Follows :

```
var asText = document.getElementById('container').innerText;
var asHTML = document.getElementById('container').innerHTML;
```

If you get a null answer without using any methods it means either your div doesn't exist or not is loaded.

**Edit** :

Don't forget to specify in the manifest.json file at which time your javascript should be executed.
You can do this by using the **run_at** parameter.

**manifest.json**

```
{
      "name": "The name of your extension",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "description": "Your description goes here",
          "homepage_url": "http://example.com/",  
      "content_scripts": [
            {
                  "run_at": "document_end",
                  "all_frames": false,
                  "matches": [
                        "*"
                  ],
                  "js": [
                        "*"
                  ]
            }
      ],
      "web_accessible_resources": [
            "*"
      ],
      "permissions": [
            "storage"
      ]
}
```

Comment: When I use that method and try and alert(asHTML) nothing appears.

Comment: It makes sense if your object returns null.
Could please provide a piece of code of your html page ?

Comment: <html>
  <head>
  <style type="text/css"></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">testing page</div>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: Is your javascript in the head section ?

Comment: No the Javascript isn't on that page, the Javascript comes from the Chrome extension. I want to make the Javascript import the HTML into the Chrome extension.

Comment: I think you need to modify the manifest.json file.
There is a paramater called "run_at", you need to set it to document_end that way your javascript will be executed after the document.
Like this one : http://jsfiddle.net/x0eax47e/1/

Comment: When I attempt to use the code from that, I get an error while trying to load it in:
Invalid value for 'content_scripts[0].matches[0]': Missing scheme separator.

Comment: Sorry i gave you this script as example, i'll fix it.

Comment: fixed : http://jsfiddle.net/x0eax47e/2/
Don't forget to replace the value of the matches parameter with the url of the website  you're trying to parse.

Comment: So I replace the * with container?

Comment: No, you replace the * with the website containing the container div.

Comment: What if the website changes? As in the link it goes to each time is different.

Comment: Is it the website that's changing or the URI ?
You can always use wildcards, so i don't think it's a problem.